# Change text color on mouse over using the style tag

Tags: html, css, hover

Using CSS it's easy to apply a custom color to a link when you hover over it using:

```
.myId:hover{
    color:green;
}
```

But what about the style tag? It is possible to do something along the lines of:

```
<a style="*insert nifty markup here to change color on hover*" href="somewhere.html">text</a>
```

Or is changing the hover color only possible trough the first method (using only html/css, no javascript allowed).

Comment: Inline styles BAD!!! Use your first idea, forget the inline style!!

Comment: You're referring to the style property, not style tag. The `<style>` tag is what goes in the head :)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, up-voted them all because they are all correct apparently. I know it's bad practice to put style in it like that, but I was curious as to if it was possible to do the hover event thing that way. Thanks all! SO is the best!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot and should not do this. Give it a class or id, and a stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

**Nope**, I don't think you can alter states or add selectors via the style tag.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can only use either the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` section, or an external stylesheet.

The first suggestion is the best. Inline styles are the most specific and can never be ovridden, also it's difficult to find them when editing. It's best to keep all CSS either in the head of an external stylsheet :) (imo)